# Write bar code in text file using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to write bar code image in text file and print using dot matrix printer in C#.

What i tried:

```
image barcode = generator.GenerateImage(); 
byte[] b = imageToByteArray(barcode); 
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(txtPath, false, Encoding.UTF8)) 
{ 
    writer.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[]) 
}
```

Comment: Show your code and error for us

Comment: you can convert that image to base64 encoding to store it in a text file..

Comment: you failed to say what type of printer (e.g., Zebra printers have their own language), what type of bar code, and any code you've attempted.

Comment: you can Convert Image to Base64 String & save in text file .

Comment: See code as: `
                              image  barcode = generator.GenerateImage();                            
                             byte[] b = imageToByteArray(barcode);
                         
                
                              using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(txtPath, false, Encoding.UTF8))
                             {                         
                               
                              writer.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])
                                     
                                }
                        `

Comment: Above code encode in text file but this is not printing on DMP.

Answer (score 0):

Barcodes are easiet done by using a barcode font. Like "free 3 of 9". Search for it. I am not sure how a dot matrix printer will handle this tho... works good on lazer's.

gonna need to be a good dot matrix printer to get enough resolution for a barcode reader....